# How to read and write input output files in yocto

Tags: c, yocto, file-handling

Hello I am trying to create an custom application where I can read and write to the files. I can use it using stdio.h library in C code. How can use this operation while building with yocto. I can create an executable, when the flash the image  on my microcontroller built with my application it says there is no input files (Yocto dosnt do file handling)
Do i need to do kernel configuration? (If yes how should i do it)

```
inherit autotools pkgconfig
inherit meson
PRIORITY = "optional"
SECTION  = "examples"
LICENSE  = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"
SRC_URI = "file://appxyz/"




S = "${WORKDIR}"
B = "${WORKDIR}/build_dir"
MESON_SOURCEPATH = "${S}/appxyz"




do_install() {

 install -d ${D}${bindir}
 install -d ${D}${libdir}

 install -m 0755 ${B}/appxyz ${D}${bindir}
 

}


FILES_${PN} +=  "${bindir}/ ${bindir}/appxyz"
```

This is recipe for my application, appxyz is the executable, how can change it to reading files?

Comment: Please clarify what exactly is complaining that there are no input files and when.

Comment: The input files are in the same directory in as main.c,  How can  i install the folder in my yocto recipe and specify the path in my main.c @IanAbbott

Comment: This is markedly not a C question